# Where's the documentation for jQuery set version of .position()?

Tags: jquery

I am not finding the documentation for jQuery set version of .position()? All I see is the get version at http://api.jquery.com/position.

The usage is like:

```
jQuery(theElement).position({
            my: "center",
            at: "center",
            of: ElementPositionedAgainstTo,
            offset: "0 0"
        });
```

Comment: Probably because there is none. Retrieve coordinates, then calculate your needed position and apply with `.css();`... Just an idea, tho'.

Answer (score 5):

That is jQuery UI [`.position()`](http://ui-dev.jquery.com/demos/position/)

Comment: I thought it was a core one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Tony's comment is correct. Use:

```
.css({top:'21px',left:'431px'})
```

for position *relative to parent* (which, yes, confusingly is css-wise position:absolute). Unless you truly want to set things absolute to the document edges. In that case use [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), which does have a setter variant (and will do a hell lot of math for you calculating offsets ascending through the tree)

**The usual caveats:**

- don't forget px as units. Unless you fancy something else like 'em'...
- object needs CSS style 'position:absolute;' and 'display:block' (unless implicit)
- direct parent must be position:relative (or absolute, but at least something set, as a 'stopper')